# Jumping only when the hero is above the platform - Spritekit game

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, 2d-games

Hi everyone For the pass two days I was trying to solve the problem I'm having without success..

I want to make game when the hero jumps on platform and goes up. It is Doodle Jump type of a game.

Here is the code

I make the the world node

```
SKNode *world;
```

Then the hero

```
SKSpriteNode *hero;
// setting the physicsBody
// add categoryBitMask = heroCat;
// add contactTestBitMask = platformCat;
// add collisionBitMask = 0;
```

The platform

```
SKSpriteNode *platform;
// setting the physicsBody
// add categoryBitMask = platformCat;
// add collisionBitMask = 0;
```

In didBeginContact

```
// Only bounce the hero if he's falling
if (hero.physicsBody.velocity.dy < 0){
     hero.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(hero.physicsBody.velocity.dx, 500.0f);
}
```

In didSimulatePhysics

```
// if the game is started and the hero position is > 0 and hero position > the new max hero y
if(self.isStarted && hero.position.y > 0 && hero.position.y > _maxHeroY){
    CGPoint positionInScene = [self convertPoint:hero.position fromNode:hero.parent];
    world.position = CGPointMake(world.position.x, world.position.y -positionInScene.y);
}
```

So far so good but what the I notice that sometimes I can jump when:
            in didSimulatePhysics i also gen new platform on random Y with fixed x value from the preveos platform
            when the hero goes up the world position change
            the hero is falling
            he is not above the platform but abble to contact with his body, this is wrong cause he has to jump only when the feet are above the platform

So I change the didBeginContact

```
// hero position in the world 
CGPoint positionInScene = [self convertPoint:hero.position fromNode:node.parent];

// platform position in the world
CGPoint positionInSceneP = [self convertPoint:node.position fromNode:node.parent];

// get the positon of the bottom edge of the hero (the feet)
int heroBottomEdge = positionInScene - hero.frame.size.height/2;

// get the positon of the top edge of the platfrom
int platformTopEdge = positionInScene - node.frame.size.height/2;


// Only bounce the hero if he's falling and the bottom edge of the hero node(the feet) is above the platform top edge or or equal to jump
if (hero.physicsBody.velocity.dy < 0 && heroBottomEdge >= platformTopEdge){
     hero.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(hero.physicsBody.velocity.dx, 500.0f);
}
```

The problem is that sometimes platformTopEdge is bigger that the heroBottomEdge and ther hero pass through the platform without jumping
                I also try with just hero.position.y and node.position.y but the effect is the same

Comment: What is the size of your physics body? Are you using the same rectangle as your sprite?

Comment: hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];

Comment: platform.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:platform.size]; // width 70, height 17

Comment: I can't really try it, but can you try with hero physics body of
40 width 1 height with the center at the feet of your hero sprite.

And do the same with you platform put only with a 1px tick at the top of the sprite.

Comment: Is this correct hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(0, 39) toPoint:CGPointMake(40, 40)];

Comment: I think it more like 

hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(0, 40) toPoint:CGPointMake(40, 40)]; 

and 0,0 -> 0,17 for your platform, I wonder how it works out with that?

I am not 100% sure how SpriteKit will handle it

Comment: [hero.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0.0f, 20.0f)]; - this don't make the hero to jump

Comment: maybe the way the physics is handle it does not support parallet lines collision.

You can try making the hit box at the feet of the hero a bit thicker? using the from rectangle:center constructor?

Maybe the velocity made the collision very improbable

Comment: "using the from rectangle:center constructor" what do you mean?

Comment: + (SKPhysicsBody *)bodyWithRectangleOfSize:(CGSize)s center:(CGPoint)center

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(40, 40) center:CGPointMake(0, 40)] like so ?

Comment: [Drawing](http://imgur.com/T2U5HRw)
about maybe that maybe
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(40, 5) center:CGPointMake(20, 38)]

Comment: the platform PhysicsBody is not right - node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(0, 16) toPoint:CGPointMake(0, 17)];

Comment: platform  - [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(70, 1) center:CGPointMake(0, 16)];

hero  - [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(40, 5) center:CGPointMake(0, 5)];

With settings the hero goes inside the platform..

Comment: I also have self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);